# For a web site using Polymer, where to place html files?

Tags: polymer

I am developping a web site using google Polymer framework. I want to ask if you can place src html files in folders other than the default src folder?

For example, I have too many html files in the default src folder. And it is hard to manage the file names.

Or I have some original componet html files which I want to place somewhere other than the default src folder.

I know it is possible for test projects. However I worry that it will somehow prevent the final from benefitting from Polymer framework.

Comment: Could you not just try it and see if it works?

Comment: @M.Babcock,At present, I cannot estimate the final size of the source code of the web site. Even if it works efficiently currently, I worry the case it won't for the final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could organize your files into directories, and they don't necessarily need to be under `src/`. For example, given the Polymer-CLI-generated `app-drawer-template`, you could move `my-view1.html` into its own directory at the top-level of the project:

```
.
├── README.md
├── images
│   ├── app-icon-144.png
│   ├── app-icon-32.png
│   └── app-icon.svg
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── my-view1*
│   └── my-view1.html*
├── polymer.json*
├── service-worker.js
├── src
│   ├── my-app.html*
│   ├── my-icons.html
│   ├── my-view2.html
│   └── my-view3.html
├── sw-precache-config.js
└── test
    ├── index.html
    └── my-view1.html*
```

You'd have to tweak some files (see starred files in list above) that currently expect `my-view1.html` under `src/`, and update any paths (e.g., HTML imports) in `my-view1.html`. Otherwise, `polymer build` yields somewhat cryptic errors when it can't resolve a path.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you to follow the [polymer starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) project. They have created the hello world app with some basic structure. That's pretty scalable. I'm building production level app using that.

Plus points if you follow...

1. Few of the best talented minds in web development have contributed to that project.
2. It does have setup to vulcanize your polymer app. that will create only one file for production to deploy all your components in just one html file.
3. It does have all the cream & butter require to make progressive web apps
4. It includes unit testing